# How to dynamically exclude sortable item while dragging?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists:

```
<ul class='list_one'>
<li>drag me</li>
<li>drag me</li>
</ul>

<ul class='list_two'>
<li class='first'>top most</li>
<li class='middle'>here i am</li>
<li class='middle'>here i am</li>
<li class='last'>least most</li>
</ul>
```

I want to prevent the first and last items in the second list from being sorted or shifted at all.  They are to remain in those positions permanently.

The issue is that when a placeholder shadow is cast, the last item gets pushed down, out of the fixed spot.

```
jQuery('ul.sq-ranksort-buckets').sortable({
  connectsWith: 'ul.sq-ranksort-cards',
  items: "li:not(.last_dropped, .suppress_move)",
  cancel: ".ui-sortable-disabled, .suppress_move, .do_not_drop, ul.do_not_drop",
  over: function( event, ui ) {
    if(jQuery('.suppress_move.last:visible').length === 0) {
        jQuery(this).addClass('do_not_drop');
        jQuery(ui.item).addClass('last_dropped');
        console.log('should cancel happen: ' + jQuery('.do_not_drop').length);
    } else {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('do_not_drop');
        jQuery(ui.item).removeClass('last_dropped');
        console.log('should cancel happen: ' + jQuery('.do_not_drop').length);
    }
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/5zuncdhh/)

I was wondering if there is way to dynamically recast what is typically canceled mid sort, specified by a class and then, have an event trigger as though you had dropped the sort in an un-sortable area?

This is the approach I have to take because I do not have control over the original sortable invocation and options, nor can I simply re-cast it with limited functionality.

Comment: So when `.list_two` has 4 items, and a 5th is dragged in, do you want `.first` and `.last` to remain at their current indexes? Or should `.last` be allowed to move as long as it remains the last item?

Comment: @Twisty .last should not event be allowed to "shift", it should never have an opportunity to be shifted.  Even in the jQuery UI API for sortable, in their example, even though they disable certain items, their index will be altered and shifted in certain dragging scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a typo in your code. I have made a new fiddle based on yours.
There is an issue in the newest jQuery UI version and ".sortable('instance')", so I choose the version 1.11.4.

The "over" option gives you the scrolling ability for both list and the "stop" option function re-order the second list. This was necessary when removing all items from list_two (exept the first and last item).
Hope this is what you are searching for.

here is the new code:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
        items: "li:not(.first, .last)",
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        over: function(e, ui){
            $(ui.sender).sortable('instance').scrollParent = $(e.target)
        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {
            if ( $('.list_two li').length < 4 ) {
                $('.list_two li:eq(2):not(.first, .last)').after($('.list_two li:eq(1)'));
            }
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9tLzwpra/7/

Comment: How exactly are you preventing the shadow from pushing the last item out of the index.

Comment: don`t really know what you mean with "preventing the shadow..." but if you remove all items from list_two, then the stop function will reorder the items after dragging one more item and push the item after the first item.